# An error getting (Error: 30007) Carrier violation from Twilio

Tags: twilio

We've a Twilio integration, and for one device SMS functionality it works well. But for another device which is in the same region, it does not work using same message content and also 'test' content. I am getting the below error:

> Programmable SMS Logs
>
> status of SMS is :
>
> (Error: 30007) Carrier violation. Your message content was flagged as going against carrier guidelines.

Comment: Hey, any chance you can share what the message contents are?

Comment: test, !r3,1,101  this are the two seperate message i'm sending to the device

Comment: I would follow up with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this. They can likely give you more details about the failure and advice on not violating carrier guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You were filtered out as spam
30007 - Carrier Violation
Your message was flagged as objectionable by the carrier. In order to protect their subscribers, many carriers have implemented content or spam filtering.

Comment: is this an answer? an error message?

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear - the error message is the answer. The sender repeatedly sent a “test” message and it’s being filtered out. Try another string for a message

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).